# I want to search in firebase through user name

Tags: iphone, swift, xcode, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am facing an issue in retrieving a data present in node

Dev->Regis->[userId("hjgsfgsdfghd8ydfsw3r")]->UserInfo->{userName:"", email:""}

I am trying the following query

```
 ref.child(kChild).child(kRegistration).queryOrdered(byChild: kUserInfo).queryEqual(toValue: searchText).observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in 
       if snapshot.exists() {    
            }
        }
```

I also tries by making rules but it does make result

```
"Development": {
    "Registration": {
      "$user_id": {
            "UserInfo": {
                    ".indexOn": ["userName"],
                ".read": "auth.uid == $user_id"
                    }
            }
     }
  }
```

database structure

[image: see the structure]

and ref means Database.refrence()

Please help to sort out this problem.

Thanks.

Comment: you need to provide your database structure as well and what does that ref point to

Comment: edited. please check now.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming searchText is the username value that you want to grab the object for. Firebase requires an orderBy call.

```
let searchText = //username you wish to fetch
let ref = db.ref('Development/Registration/${userId}/userInfo')
ref.orderByChild('userName').equalTo(searchText).once("value", function(snapshot) {
    if(snapshot.exists()){
       //whatever you want to do here
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to search in entire Registration node not for particular UserInfo node.

Comment: you cant do double nested queries as far as i know.
Also check this post which explains a similar situation
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27207059/firebase-query-double-nested

Comment: NO, firebase changed. this feature is added. By the way thanks for link you above sent. By that link I solved my problem. yippee.  A Big Thank you